# Joomla send server error code instead of error message?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

Occasionally our site goes down because of overload issues with the MySQL DB.  Things like max users connected, or the DB is unreachable.  I am wondering if there is any way to change so that instead of serving these error messages, the could instead serve out a 5XX server error code?

Main reason is that if this was kicked out instead of the message, our CDN would serve up stale, but visible, content instead of just displaying the error message and caching that.

Comment: Do you manage the server yourself and what type is it?

Comment: It is managed by a server company, but is a dedicated server. CentOS release 6.6

Comment: One idea would be along the lines of prevention is better then the cure.  I've had issues in the past with MySQL crashing and its usually do to configuration or specs; however I've mitigate the issue with cron job to check if MySQL service is running, and to start it if not.

Comment: outside of that, you could add logic to the entry index.php to attempt a connection to the DB, and if that fails throw a custom error or display cached content.  This is not ideal either however as any update to this file by Joomla would destroy any customization.

Comment: Yeah I figured there would have to be some sort of core hack, was hoping to be able to just tap into the error reporting section of joomla.  Just haven't been able to isolate it yet.

Comment: Then I would honestly go with a server level solution, since that's really where the issue is occurring.  I would suggest a bash script schedule to run every couple of minutes or so and check is the MySQL service is running, and if not, start it up again.

Comment: However, the main issue is not that it has stopped running, but it is simply overloaded.  Not sure how a script could check availability until it was already gone.

Comment: Overloaded?   Again,  I still think this sounds like a server side mysql configuration issue.  The solution isn't too find a workaround to mysql becoming overloaded, but to find and correct root cause causing the failure.  Which is most likely a configuration issue or too much load for the hardware.  Start with the mysql error logs, see if you can track down root cause is best solution.